# Vertically center a div inside a display: table-cell element?

Tags: css, center

I am trying to center a `div` inside a `table-cell` element. I really tried all the previous answers but I simply could not figure it out. Here is the code I am using:

- HTML skeleton:

  ```
  <div class="selection">
      <div class="selection_empty">
          <p>No selection.</p>
          <p>Click the button below to start the process.</p>
          <span class="selection_icon ico_add_medium"></span>
      </div>
  </div>
  ```

[image: Rendered HTML]

- CSS style:

  ```
  .selection {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  }
  ```

As I mentioned, I tried everything I found on but nothing did the trick. I would really appreciate your help! Thank you!

Comment: You should change your post to say "vertically center" a div, rather than "center", as that usually implies horizontal alignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: middle` because is a table cell style, if you change the table cell style the trick will be other, but without changing nothing:

```
.selection {
  display: table-cell;  
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I add the fiddle link to show this works:

https://jsfiddle.net/qL5sf9uo/

Comment: Hey, don't downvote if you don't know about this topic. It works perfectly, see the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qL5sf9uo/

Comment: Dont put the fiddle here. Up There ^^^^

Comment: I edit the answer 1 minute ago with the link, however, I'm not meritory of your downvote. I hope this helps to OP

Comment: Thank you, it worked like a charm. You determined me to study more carefully the `display: table` properties.